# Caching issue serving images from OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, openshift

I'm using the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to store user-uploaded images because this directory is not re-written on deployment. I've got a symlink set up for referencing the directory in the markup:

```
app.use('/media', express.static(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + '/media/'))
```

Then I can use that in the markup like so:

```
<img src="media/images/xyz.jpg" />
```

This works great locally, however, when I deploy I get a 404 on those images until I clear the browser cache. I doubt this has anything to do with it, but in case it helps, I'm using Angular on the front end, and those image paths are more like this:

```
<img src="media/images/{{user.profileImage}}" />
```

I know very little about server admin, and any help/thoughts/whatever is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

@coreydaley pointed me in the right direction, but I wanted to post my complete solution as an answer for anyone who happens upon this.

My issue was indeed due to the fact that my app scales across gears and those gears don't share a common file system, even in the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. In researching I found [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/). The Node API is super easy to use and they offer tons of storage on their free plan. Not to mention the image manipulation tools, which so far seem to be rockin.

I am doing uploads like so:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.file.path, function (result)
{
    if (result)
    {
        var thumbUrl = cloudinary.url(result.public_id + '.' + result.format, { width: 100, height: 100, crop: 'fill' });

        res.json({
            success: 1, 
            successMessage: 'Successfully uploaded file: ' + req.files.file.originalname, 
            fileName: req.files.file.name, 
            photoUrl: result.url, 
            thumbUrl: thumbUrl 
        });
    }
// Using the original filename as cloudinary's public_id
}, { use_filename: true});
```

And listing my uploaded resources on the client side like so:

```
cloudinary.api.resources(function (result)
{ 
    if (result)
    {
        var files = [];

        async.each(result.resources, function (file, next)
        {
            var thumbUrl = cloudinary.url(file.public_id + '.' + file.format, { width: 100, height: 100, crop: 'fill' });
            files.push(thumbUrl);
            next();
        }, function (err)
        {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.json({ success: 1, files: files });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

users who visit your website do not have direct access to your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, as it is outside of your web directory.  You may need to create a symlink into your web directory for your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media folder for it to work.  Also, if you are using a scaled application the file system is not shared between gears.  if you could point us at the actual application url that has a sample of the issue, it would help.

Comment: I'm using `express.static()` to create a symlink to the DATA_DIR, and the files are there. It must be a file system issue between gears. You can go [here](http://dc-necstage.rhcloud.com/store/categories) for an example. Those images are producing a 404 for me right now, but will show up if I clear my browsing history (cached images/files, app data, etc). Maybe the answer is to restart the app each time I deploy?

Comment: So, it looks like you are using a scaled application ( 2x node.js gears), they won't share a filesystem, whenever you upload an image, it gets stored on only one of the gears.  You should use a module and upload the images to amazon s3 and serve them from there (or another similar file service)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I posted my complete solution as an answer in case other folks find themselves in the same predicament.